# Inkscape: realistic lighting and shading

Tags: vector, inkscape

Graphics have never been my force, so i decided to close this gap.
After learning the basics of Inkscape and SVG, i'm trying to give more "reality" to my drawings.
I have a circle which i want to make appear as a realistic sphere.
After following [this tutorial](https://inkscapetutorials.org/2014/10/02/7-steps-for-improving-your-lighting-effects-in-inkscape/) and playing with gradients and blurs, this was the result:

[image: I think cast shadow can be longer, but that won't get it any closer to my idea]

What i want is mainly a polished surface, or even if the matter has the same consistency as it is, at least an improved border. How to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51538/how-can-i-make-a-shape-look-like-it-is-made-of-glass and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/prototype-visualization-how-can-i-learn-to-render-glass-convincingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is rewritten because it contained much clutter which was gradually fixed due the given comments. In addition Inkscape 1.0 works a little better than older versions. The comments are now obsolete. The older revisions are readable and the comments are valid for before 2021 versions.

Draw a plausible greyshade sphere by applying a radial gradient to a circle. Make also a duplicate of the circle and fill it with solid color:

[image]

Place (align or have point snaps ON) the grey version above the colored version. Let the grey version have blending mode = Luminosity.

[image]

You can as well have the colored version on top and let it have blending mode = Color. The result is the same.

The white area can present a gloss which is too bright to be shown as colored in the RGB system. If you want the brightest area as colored you cannot have full white in the gradient. Or you can if the used blending mode is = Multiply.

In the next version the blending mode is still = Luminosity, but the bright spot is substantially darker. The colored version in the bottom has got a brighter color to compensate the darkening:

[image]

There's another answer which doesn't use blending with grey gradient for shading, the gradient contais all needed colors. That, of course, gives the best control, but you cannot experiment easily with different colors nor use imported images as surface color.

The shadow can be made as blurred grey or black ellipse. Here's 2 elementary versions:

[image]

Placing the shadow and coloring it realistically is as tricky as creating the shading of the sphere. The shadow must be in accordance with the direction of the light, how the light is projected (=does it generate sharp shadow edges and is it uniform) and how much there's diffuse ambient light. I skip the details.

I guess you may want glossy reflections. Making them needs an assumption of what's around the sphere. Some cliches like a curved window or ellipse, of course, can be drawn quite easily, but there can be more. They are beyond the scope of this answer.

**Photos as surface**

[image]

You must import an already spherically distorted photo as PNG with transparent background. Then you use it as the color. Inkscape works in 2D, it has no idea how a photo should be distorted for right 3D geometry appearance.

Comment: Ok i followed your advices as much as i could and this is the actual result:
https://ibb.co/kAOqWQ

Comment: Wow i didn't see your addendum! :o i'll test that too!

Comment: @DanieleSqualo About your sphere: You have quite bright color. Maybe you should try to make the black end a little darker and add some opacity to the mid stop. The monkey: It needs a spherically distorted photo. It's easy to make in Photoshop or equivalent and import as PNG. The grey sphere overlay must be in another layer that has blending mode Hard light. Simply dragging the grey sphere onto the photo flattens the contrast too much. Messing with photos is easiest to do in GIMP or Photoshop. You lose nothing because the photos ruin the infinite scalability anyway.

Comment: Opacity in middle stop confuses ball's color. Doing just the outer stop to a full black goes to this: https://ibb.co/hzaR5k

Comment: Look at what happens when i change color to something strong: https://ibb.co/kWwAWQ Isn't it the case to add another stop with alpha=100%?

Comment: @DanieleSqualo This grey overlay method simply is not good for strong colors. It only helps to make differently colored copies and have textures. Stromg colors need the same as photos - another layer with blending mode. User Rafael seemingly has a little different version that works with stromg colors. His gradient mid stop is the color. But it can't have textures. I'll add something to my answer about how to use the blending modes and layers. It takes few hours.

Comment: Thank you! I could not imagine that was a so complex matter

Comment: @DanieleSqualo The shaded sphere -story has completed with a variation that does not need flat and dull color, but needs 2 layers. It's not especially complex. Only 2 layers - today people easily have ten or tens of layers in their artwork files. I bet you will join them as soon as  you get the idea, how useful they are. Method 2 works in GIMP, Photoshop and Illustrator.

Comment: Thank you for precious advices. Testing back and forth atm. I'll post again when i'll have some nice results,

Comment: I'm trying method 2 atm. This is what i'm getting and i like it https://ibb.co/gs7UQk
Instead i dislike the result with black https://ibb.co/cmbpQk

Comment: @DanieleSqualo It's theoretically impossible to shade black darker. The only way to get an illusion of a black sphere is to make it glossy - you must draw spherically distorted, but sharp and partially transparent  reflected images of the environment. Easy only to talk and write, the actual doing is something totally else.

Answer (score 6):

My two cents.

In my opinion, you have some problems.

You are not wrapping the lower end in a shadow.

The main gradient should consist of 3 color nodes.

- The first one, the center one is not white. It is the actual color I want the object to be. That makes the color more solid.
- The last one is pretty dark. Take a look at this: [How can I make the color white look as white as possible?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58735/how-can-i-make-the-color-white-look-as-white-as-possible/58737#58737) on how to achieve a good gradient.
- And I added an additional node, first at the center. Playing a bit with it gives me control of the shadow. It is not at the center but displaced to the dark side... Luke...

This is how the gradient looks:[image]

[image]

I added a glossy reflection (if you need a glossy material), it is just a white ellipse with a transparent gradient. It could be a curved rectangle or any shape. This shape corresponds to the shape of the reflected light source. Take a look at these two posts regarding the materials:

- [How can I make a shape look like it is made of glass?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51538/how-can-i-make-a-shape-look-like-it-is-made-of-glass)
- [Prototype Visualization: How can I learn to render glass convincingly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/prototype-visualization-how-can-i-learn-to-render-glass-convincingly)

Additionally really control the position of the shadow, yours do not match the position of the highlight.

The height of this shadow gives the illusion of camera position regarding the floor.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing I see is the lack of a shadow on the sphere, realistically your shadow does not match the strength of its highlight. your gradient goes from a white > skyblue (or whichever). If you can adjust the gradient do white > skyblue > really dark blue (like almost black blue), it might help. Remeber, the stronger the light, the stronger the shadow. As if its 12 noon and not a cloud in the sky, the shadows are darker and crisper, if a cloud is blocking the light the objects become more dull (grayish), and so the shadows lighten up as well.

Another area is the edge of the sphere, its too sharp so it does not blend in with the background. if you have a blur tool, blur the edges. The way the cast-shadow edges are blurred.

Extra realism: to really make it feel real, get some textures online and overlay them on your object, like metal texture, etc.

Here's a little sample I did in photoshop trying to fix that.
[image]

Comment: It's way better now. Understood all you told about colors and shadows; but what about blurred edges? The more i blur, the more the whole item is big. Is this to be done before or after the lightning? And how much should i blur? Thank you again.