# Trying to design a 3D sheet in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, 3d

I am trying to obtain this effect of layered structure on the series of spheres that I have drawn. But skewing and rotating the spheres aren't resulting in the desired effect. Any hint on how do I go about doing this?

Thank you[image]

[image]

Skewing and rotation is resulting in distortion of the spheres

I tried your suggestion. Also tried to add a bit extra by using isometric grid. The result though doesn't exactly has the 3D feel. [image]

Comment: I suppose that is not your drawing... so, How can we tell?

Comment: I really don't think Inkscape is the right software for this. It has no 3D capabilities. You probaably want a 3D modelling application instead, such as Blender.

Comment: @Rafael, included below is my drawing. if you see, the spheres are losing their shape

Comment: Take a look at this post on how to draw a sphere. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/inkscape-realistic-lighting-and-shading/90478#90478

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me play with this:

A. Duplicate your sphere

B. Duplicate your row and place it a bit down

C. And move it a bit to one side, to the left on this example.

D Repeat several times.

This could be one "isometric" style (It is not really isometric) but you do not have any perspective at all.

[image]

F. So you could now scale the second row and keep scaling the next ones.

G. This also works.

H. But now, if you move them to the left as the other example, it looks distorted.

[image]

I. So, you now need to scale incrementally also on each row

J. But now it looks like the graph is rolled, so

K. Compensate a bit rolling to the right.

[image]

L. You can do the same modifications to the Z axis. I will just duplicate the "isometric" version.

But you will notice now that the layer below, should not "glow" because it has a layer of spheres above...

[image]

If you are ok until this point, keep doing it in 2D software. But if you want more realism... Switch to 3D

[image]

(This image was way faster than the 2D versions)

Comment: Wow the layer K looks really nice! Thanks!

Comment: :) The real problem will be the shade of the lower layers.

Comment: Which software did you use?

Comment: For the 3D, Blender.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Billy Kerr that Blender is the appropriate tool to use.

I was able to get the following effect on Inkscape.
[image: Stack of spheres]

I followed these steps:

1. Create a single circle with 2-point radial gradient
2. Add a 100% white background to the circle to eliminate any transparency effects.
3. Align to form a row, then offset to create a plane.
4. Finally, copy a new plane on top of the first one.

Some more work is required to create a parallax effect.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried it the way you described. I may have to play around with the gradient a wee bit

Comment: I had to add a second stop to the gradient to get the darker shade at the bottom right corners.