# Adobe Illustrator: put a radial gradient over solid background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I am trying to create 3d ball in Illustrator. I have the following strategy:

- create a solid colour background;
- create a "diffuse" shape;
- create a "reflection" shape;
- mix them together.

Final result should look like this:
[image]

The problem is that radial gradient has a "background" color. To mix it with background figure properly I use "multiply mode", but then it mixes active colour as well.

Another solution might be to create a radiant gradient from *transparency* to active colour, but how?

How do I create such a illustration, consisting of two shapes in AI:

[image]

Comment: not a duplicate, but can have something useful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108950/creating-a-transparent-sphere-for-highlight-shadow

Answer (score 5):

### Shape 1

- A circumference with a radial gradient fill

[image]

### Shape 2

- Fill 100% white, Hard Light Mode, 40% and a Feather effect

[image: shine]

### Shape 3

- A circumference with a linear gradient stroke, 90º, from black 100% to
  black 0%, and a Feather effect.
- Mode Multiply, 60%

[image]

Result

[image: Ball]

Comment: I will be much obliged if you share your layers window screenshot as well.

Comment: :-) It's just one layer, three shapes

Comment: You mean shape2 is just over shape1 and not in between background and radial gradient fill?

Comment: The shapes order is exactly the same as the answer order, the 3rd shape has no fill, is a ring

Comment: Nice solution! But is there a way to split Shape1 into tho different shapes: solid background colour and white radial gradient fill? (The purpose is to be able to put Shape2 in between them.)

Comment: @DenisKulagin Yes, make a blue circumference as a Shape 0 and the same shape as the shape 1 but with a radial gradient from white to white, from 100% to 0% opacity.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually do quite a bit with only the **Appearance Panel**

[image]

Stacking multiple fills with various gradients and then transforming the fills can allow you to keep one object which can easily be color changed or saved as a **graphic Style** to apply later.

And.. if you want the orb to be translucent, merely remove the base fill (And possibly adjust the gradients on the shadows/reflection so they are radial rather than linear)...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Layering different types of light effects makes the shape complex, generating variations will be tricky. Illustrators 3D effect Revolve creates easily a sphere with the wanted glossy oval reflection + shading. The light and the reflection are adjustable in the effect dialog:

[image]

In the left there's a copy of the revolved half circle. An extra light was added to get the oval reflection.

A circle with three stop gradient fill was inserted on top with blending mode Hard light for the other shading:

[image]

The inserted circle and its white - grey - lighter grey gradient are shown in the left.