# How to create a shadow looking sphere and a glass looking spheres?

Tags: inkscape, effects, shadows

I'm having a difficulty trying to recreate the glassy sphere from the bottom using Inkscape. Can someone help me with a step by step guide or something similar?. I've tried to reproduce this object. But I don't know how to achieve the glassy effect.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The figure from below is a second example which I also intend to recreate but I don't know how to do it. The upper portions are trimmed so I don't know how it would be those gaps, I'm only assuming it follows the path of the shade.

[image: Sketch of the second problem]

I guess that this image has different layers but I don't know how to achieve this. I intend to use it at the end of one rod so the whole image must be copied. Can someone help me?. I'm stuck with this.

The figure from below is the second part of my question:

[image: Sketch of the third problem]

How can I creste a sphere which has an inner shadow and a blurry shadow?. Can someone help me with how to create the effect as seen in the three objects?. I'm stuck with that part. Which tools should I use?. Can someone help me with this?.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51538/how-can-i-make-a-shape-look-like-it-is-made-of-glass/51557#51557

Comment: And this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/inkscape-realistic-lighting-and-shading/90478#90478

Answer (score 2):

Draw the circle, and apply a radial gradient. Then look at the highlights and the shapes they make. Try to reproduce these using the Bézier tool to draw solid filled shapes, fill them with lighter colours, and reduce their opacity, or add a blur to some of them.

Here's a very quick example I made showing the pieces, their fills, opacity and blur.

[image]

Comment: The gif it is a bit speed up and I cannot distinguish the changes which you made to the drawing. Can you add a more longer version?. I don't know exactly which are the shapes which should be added to get that effect. I can see that there are some ellipses over the circle but not exactly on which colors should be used.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - I'm sorry, but I didn't save the drawing. The changes I made were just to the fill colour, and the opacity and blur sliders, nothing complicated. Also the shapes themselves can be seen as I select each one. Only the circle is an ellipse, the rest are just shapes I drew with the Pen Tool (aka the Bézier tool).

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to "see" the elements that compose an illustration.

Think of every element as a single shape. Each reflection has one, probably you need to intersect some other shapes.

Here is a diagram showing in simple steps diferent elements.

Use gradients, and transparencies.

[image]

Comment: I'm not very fond of the use of transparencies. The illusion of glass which seems to appear in the third drawing from the left is it composed by a white ellipse behind a gray gradient?. I'm lost at that part, can you explain this part please?. I'd like to learn about this.